# Python Selenium - handle InvalidArguementException -File not Found

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a script that loads a file into a browser using send_keys which works fine, however I wanted to handle an exception when the file is not found but cant figure out the way to do this, I have tried to catch InvalidArgumentException and IOError  but neither of them seem to catch the exception

```
chooseFile = driver.find_element_by_class_name("GDTLPL2DNW");

try:
   chooseFile.send_keys("C:/temp/File.xml")

except IOError as e:
   print ("Unable to Locate xml file to import, please check source directory")
   exit( 
else:
    pass 



DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56828/devtools/browser/0ea61685-38fb-4b23-9
92b-f16031cffa1a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\FileLoadv3.py", line 132, in <module>
    chooseFile.send_keys("C:/temp/File.xml")
  File "C:\Users\hkijd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\hkijd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\hkijd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\hkijd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pack
ages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument:
File not found : C:/temp/File.xml
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

Comment: except Exception as e: Try this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to do this. Just check if the file exists using `os.path.isfile` before I start any of the rest of it.